# Omnet++ Veins Building Problem on MAC No rule to make target

Tags: gcc, build, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to build Veins on my MACOS. I am not very experienced with building. I got an error and I cannot solve. The problem is when trying to build:

```
    02:57:23 **** Incremental Build of configuration gcc-release for project veins ****
    make MODE=release -j7 all 
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target `../out/gcc-         release/src/veins/base/connectionManager/BaseConnectionManager.o', needed by `../out/gcc-      release/src/libveins.dylib'.  Stop.
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    make MODE=release -j7 all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

    02:57:24 Build Failed. 2 errors, 0 warnings. (took 271ms)
```

First I tried to building by importing veins into Omnet++ as project. It gave me that error.

I also tried to build through CLI. I opened in the directory of veins. I commanded "source setenv" and "./configure" When I try to "make" it gave me the same error.

I tried adding the path to .zshrc as

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Tugrul/veins-veins-5.2
    export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Tugrul/veins-veins-5.2/bin
    export PATH=$PATH:/Users/Tugrul/veins-veins-5.2/src
```

However, I couldn't build Veins. Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

There is definitely something misconfigured here, at least based on those lot of spaces in the filename.

As you are not experienced in resolving issues and there is not enough information in the post to figure out what's the problem, I suggest to try  [opp_env](https://github.com/omnetpp/opp_env?tab=readme-ov-file#installing-opp_env-on-linux-and-macos) and install veins trough that. Once you set op opp_env properly, it will deal with all the details to set up veins correctly. You just have to type `opp_env shell --install veins-latest`